# Erro "As configurações para acessar a impressora '"' não são válidas."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp, impressão, impressora

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.Net MVC que faz venda de produto e impressão dessa venda trabalhamos com diversas marcas de impressoras térmicas(não fiscal) como: Tanca, Bematech, Epson, entre outras.. usamos para imprimir o spooler do windows, porem, recentemente o cliente comprou um computador que já vem com a impressora integrada a ele.. quando enviamos a impressão da venda ocorre o seguinte erro:
"As configurações para acessar a impressora 'CUSTOM_IMPRESSORA' não são válidas."

Estamos fazendo a impressão da seguinte maneira:

```
    public void impressaoVenda(VendaModel venda, String itens)
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
        printDoc.PrintController = printController;

        PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("BOBINA", 800, 999999);
        printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;

        String nomeImpressora = venda.Funcionario_Logado.Impressora;

        int vias = 1;

        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = nomeImpressora;
        printDoc.DocumentName = "Cupom";

        this.itens = itens;
        this.venda = venda;

        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintPageVenda);
        printDoc.Print();

        limparObjetosImpressao();
    }
```

O erro ocorre ao na seguinte linha:

```
    printDoc.Print();
```

Não chegar nem a entrar no método.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema com uma da Bematech, o erro era o mesmo e aparentemente seguia quase o mesmo exemplo que você deu no código... Acessei o site da fabricante:
https://www.bematech.com.br/manuais-e-drivers/

Tinha algumas opções e após a instalação de uma dessas opções... Funcionou:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]